# How can I change an element inside my two dimensional array in python?

Tags: python, arrays

This is how I've created my two dimensional array:

```
matrix = [[0 for x in range(5)] for x in range(3)]
print(matrix)
```

Running this code returns this:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

However I want to write a function where I can ask for an input and substitute a zero in a specific place with the input. I want a way of telling the computer which zero to substitute with the input the user will give.

Comment: `matrix[i][j] = value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply use two pairs of square brackets (`[]`):

```
matrix = [[0 for x in range(5)] for x in range(3)]
def my_function(input, idx1, idx2):
    matrix[idx1][idx2] = input
```

As you'd expect the first pair of square brackets (`[]`) correspond to the outer list and the second pair of square brackets correspond to the inner list.

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(matrix, idx1, idx2, value):
    matrix[idx1][idx2] = value
```

test:

```
>>> matrix = [[0 for x in range(5)] for x in range(3)]
>>> def f(matrix, idx1, idx2, value):
...     matrix[idx1][idx2] = value
... 
>>> f(matrix, 2, 4, -99)
>>> matrix
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, -99]]
```

Perhaps this helps to see what is going on

```
>>> matrix[2]
[0, 0, 0, 0, -99]    # 3rd item of matrix
>>> matrix[2][4]
-99                  # 5th item of matrix[2]
```

Remember that indices start at `0`